# XNA: Why doesn't looping work?

Tags: xna, character

If I try to do a loop it will not work in XNA. What I want to use it for is character selection (fighter game) in that, if you press a Key (which selects a character), it will add on to the current count and then if that count equals a certain number, a message will display saying both characters have been selected. That is to prevent players from selecting/loading more than a certain amount of characters into the fighting arenas. In my case, I only want 2 characters to be loaded and no more.

My code is this:

```
int count = 1;

if (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   count = count + i;

if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))   // This will select Character A
   count += 1;
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))   // This will select Character B
   count += 1;

if (count == 2)   // This checks to see if the total count has reached 2
   // Message is displayed here
```

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Surely this isn't C#? There's no way that `if (int i = 0; i < count; i++)` even compiles, because it's nonsensical and syntactically incorrect. Even assuming that you meant `for`, what is its purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error here (and it seems this for-loop-like construct isn't even necessary. What is it's purpose? `if (int i = 0; i < count; i++)`

You're code is a logical mess so I won't try to build on it in my answer. I don't think I understand everything but here's an attempt.

You need state which is simply variables that indicate whether something has been loaded or no. You can simply use two boolean variables as follows:

```
//at the Game class level:
bool char1Selected = false;
bool char2Selected = false;

//inside Update(GameTime)
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
{
   char1Selected = true;
}

if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
{
   char2Selected = true;
}

if(char2Selected && char1Selected)
{
    //then both are selected. do something here according to your game's logic.
}
```